# Installing mod_jk in centos 7 on docker for windows

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose, centos7

I tried Apache for ubuntu in Docker (Docker for windows) in https://github.com/Paritosh-Anand/Docker-Httpd-Tomcat

The Dockerfile  is

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER <user>@<domain>.com

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apache2 libapache2-mod-jk

ADD apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

ADD worker.properties /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties

ADD jk.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf

VOLUME ["/var/log/apache2"]

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["apachectl", "-k", "start", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

However, I need to run Apache in CentOs 7, not in ubuntu. So I changed the Dockerfile to

```
FROM centos:7

MAINTAINER <user>@<domain>.com

RUN yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs update 
RUN yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install httpd 
RUN yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install mod-jk 
RUN yum clean all

ADD apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

ADD worker.properties /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties

ADD jk.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/jk.conf

VOLUME ["/var/log/apache2"]

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["apachectl", "-k", "start", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

On running, I am getting the error

```
Step 5/13 : RUN yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install mod-jk
 ---> Running in a98487a9509c
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
 * extras: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
 * updates: mirror.ehost.vn
No package mod-jk available.
Error: Nothing to do
ERROR: Service 'httpd' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y    --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install mod-jk' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is this a problem with mirror? How can I install mod_jk in docker where operating system is CentOs 7?
My Host operating system is windows 10

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you use AJP instead. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

For centos 7 you will need to compile the module from source. Consider the below Dockerfile as an example

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
RUN yum -y install httpd httpd-devel gcc* make && yum clean all

# Install mod_jk
RUN curl -SL http://mirror.sdunix.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz -o tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p src/tomcat-connectors \
    && tar xzf tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz -C src/tomcat-connectors --strip-components=1 \
    && cd src/tomcat-connectors/native/ \
    && ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs \
    && make \
    && cp apache-2.0/mod_jk.so /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ \
    && ./libtool --finish /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf src/ \
    && rm -f tomcat-connectors-1.2.40-src.tar.gz


# mod_jk conf files
ADD mod_jk.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/
ADD workers.properties /etc/httpd/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80

# Simple startup script to avoid some issues observed with container restart 
ADD run-httpd.sh /run-httpd.sh
RUN chmod -v +x /run-httpd.sh

CMD ["/run-httpd.sh"]
```

Taken from https://github.com/maeharin/apache-tomcat-docker-sample/blob/master/docker/httpd/Dockerfile